Estimated value in a dice game involving finding the sum of values of your dice
The game starts with 2 players each rolling 2 20-sided dice (each dice having numbers 1-20). Each player can roll as many additional dice as they want, keeping in mind the sum of the values of all of their dice cannot be more than 40, where in that case the player immediately loses. Each player can see the other player's first die. The goal of the game is to have a total sum more than the other player without exceeding 40.
The problem I had calculating whether one should add on a total sum of, say, 29 is that the expected value is unreliable for this purpose.
The average expected value of adding on a total sum of 29 (assuming we won't add again) is given by:
$\frac{Sum\:of\:all\:possible\:outcomes\:after\:adding}{Number\:of\:outcomes}$
which in this situation is
$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{20} 29+n}{20}$
which works out to be
$\frac{20(29)+21(10)}{20}$=$39.5$ (which does not exceed 40)
Now, let us create a theoretical total value, $x_{29}$, which outputs as the following
let the function $A(x,y)$ represent the total value after a die of value $y$ is added to a total value, $x$
$n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \:n+29<40, \:m+29≥40$
$A(x_{29},n)=40,\:A(x_{29},m)=m+28$
The average expected value of adding on a total sum of $x_{29}$ (assuming we won't add again) is:
$\frac{10(40)+\sum_{n=11}^{20} 29+n}{20}$
which works out to be
$\frac{400+445}{20}=42.25$ (which exceeds 40)
Although it is not possible for ${x_{29}}$ to exist, it is better to add on a total value of ${x_{29}}$ than on a 29 (logically) even though the average expected value of ${x_{29}}$ denotes it goes over 40 while 29 remains under 40. So what type of estimation system should I use here?

The rules are not clear.  Do you see one of your opponent's tosses each round or only on the first round?

Regardless:  I would suggest simulating the game, using various strategies.  Analytically, it seems hard to keep track of the effect of knowing  a few of your opponent's tosses.

What happens if both players bust? Do the players choose to roll one more die at a time, or do they have to declare the number of dice at the beginning? Do the players know anything about how many dice the other player chose to roll?

The solution concept you're looking for is probably the Nash equilibrium of a zero-sum game.
